# How to determine whether ob_start(); has been called already

Tags: php, output-buffering

I use output buffering for gzip compression and access to what was put out before in a PHP script:

```
if(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler")) ob_start();
```

Now if that script gets included in another script where ob_start() already is in use I get a warning:

> Warning: ob_start() [ref.outcontrol]: output handler 'ob_gzhandler' cannot be used twice in filename on line n

So I'd like to test whether `ob_start()` has already been called. I think [`ob_get_status()`](http://php.net/ob_get_status) should be what I need but what is the best way to use it in testing for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`ob_get_level`](http://php.net/ob_get_level) returns the number of active output control handlers and [`ob_list_handlers`](http://php.net/ob_list_handlers) returns a lift of those handlers. So you could do this:

```
if (!in_array('ob_gzhandler', ob_list_handlers())) {
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
} else {
    ob_start();
}
```

Although in general you can call `ob_start` any number of times you want, using [`ob_gzhandler`](http://php.net/ob_gzhandler) as handler cannot as you would compress already compressed data.

Comment: I was irritated by the [comment on the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) that claims "Sometimes, ob_get_level() may be off by 1 because at the start of the script, it will return 1 even if ob_start() has never been called". So is this a reliable way to tell?

Comment: @C.O.: That is probably be due to [output_buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering): “If [output_buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) is enabled or an anonymous function was used with `ob_start()`, `ob_list_handlers()` will return "`default output handler`".”

Answer (score 11):

```
if (ob_get_level())
    echo "ob already started";
```

Comment: I was irritated by the [comment on the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) that claims "Sometimes, ob_get_level() may be off by 1 because at the start of the script, it will return 1 even if ob_start() has never been called". So is this a reliable way to tell?

Comment: @C.O. I've read the comment, but this is not true. It will return 0 even if called at the start of the script. You could have a look at my example: http://codepad.org/SrZ4YdQn

Comment: It **is** true. Ran into it last week on a shared server. Best way to handle it is to start your code with `if(ob_get_level())ob_end_clean();` before `ob_start()`

Comment: @Michel That is probably due to server starting output buffering automatically.

Answer (score 6):

General:

```
if (ob_get_status())  {
  // ob started
}
```

More specific

```
$status = ob_get_status();
if ($status['name']=='ob_gzhandler') {
 // ob named ob_gzhandler started
}
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thanks. I'll use Gumbo's suggestion above I think.

Answer (score 2):

What about using it this way?

`if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();`

Comment: I was irritated by the [comment on the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) that claims "Sometimes, ob_get_level() may be off by 1 because at the start of the script, it will return 1 even if ob_start() has never been called". So is this a reliable way to tell?

Comment: At least there is no bug report for this kind of problem. Might be the commenters fault. http://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&search_for=ob_get_level&x=0&y=0

Comment: Yes probably but that comment was what led me to start this question. I wanted to get some opinions. So thanks.