# Getting error PHP Notice: Undefined variable: do_not_compress in my php code

Tags: php

Getting error

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: do_not_compress

in my php code.

```
session_start();
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') &&  !$do_not_compress) {
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
} else {
    ob_start();
}
```

I tried to remove the `&& !$do_not_compress` then throw another error

> PHP Warning:  ob_start(): output handler 'ob_gzhandler' cannot be used twice.
>   PHP Warning: ob_start(): failed to create buffer

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if $do_not_compress has not been set before it reaches this point then it's not going to be able to observe the value of it. If you're trying to use ! to see if it's not been set yet, then you should be using isset().

Secondly, I haven't used ob_start() but it appears to be that you can't call "ob_start('ob_gzhandler');" more than once in your code. So to fix the error there, don't. Here's something that may help you check before calling: [How to determine wether ob_start(); has been called already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010403/how-to-determine-wether-ob-start-has-been-called-already)